# Non-breaking space (`~') should have been used in table

Tags: ref, chktex

I am making a table with `\ref{key}` as only content in the first column. I am dynamically referring to item numbers in an `\enumerate{}`. CHKTeX gives me the warning `` Non-breaking space (`~') should have been used. ``.
I've tried adding a tilde in front of the `\ref` but then CHKTeX gives the warning `Double space found.`.

How do I get rid of this warning?

Current input:

```
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
        ~\ref{key}        &   & x & x &   &   &   \\ 
        ~\ref{anotherkey} & x & x & x &   &   &   \\ 
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: chktex is not tex and its warnings can be wrong, but without seeing any input it is impossible to guess whether anything is wrong with your document, and if so, what to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mininmal example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Zzzz\label{zz}}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\ref{zz}  & zzzz\\
\ref{zzz}  & zzzz  zzz\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Zzzz zzz\label{zzz}}


\end{document}
```

which produces

```
Warning 2 in dd197.tex line 8: Non-breaking space (`~') should have been used.
\ref{zz}  & zzzz\\  
^
Warning 2 in dd197.tex line 9: Non-breaking space (`~') should have been used.
\ref{zzz}  & zzzz  zzz\\  
^
```

These warnings are simply incorrect so ignoring them or not running chktex would be a reasonable option.

You do not want to force bad spacing or unnecessarily complicated code just to silence an incorrect syntax checker but it seems you can do this if you want and put the ref in a group

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Zzzz\label{zz}}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
{\ref{zz}}  & zzzz\\
{\ref{zzz}}  & zzzz  zzz\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Zzzz zzz\label{zzz}}


\end{document}
```

has no warnings

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself:
Using the suggested `~` from CHKTeX creates a space in front of the item. Instead the correct way to do this is `\nolinebreak`. This is a tilde but invisible. You can also add spaces in front, without generating a warning. This way the code is still indented but there is no space added. The code will look like this:

```
    \nolinebreak\ref{reqBoot} &   & x & x &   &   &   \\ 
    \nolinebreak\ref{reqDisplays} &   &   & x &   &   &   \\ 
    \nolinebreak\ref{reqBoot} &   & x & x &   &   &   \\
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The `~` before `\ref` there will disturb the spacing, I would definitely not do that.

Comment: There is a space in front, you are correct. For now this works for me, if there appears another answer that does not have the spacing I will mark that one as correct.

Comment: simply remove the  `~` that _is_ the answer the message from chktex is incorrect

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the warning on only this spot? I am obsessed with keeping my warnings down to zero.

Comment: taking heed of warnings from latex is good practice, forcing bad typeset output to avoid warnings from an incorrect checker that is not using tex at all is  less so...

Comment: I figured it out, now for good. Should I edit out the first part of my answer to avoid confusion?

Comment: it would be better to lose the `~` suggestion, yes thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope this is a useful answer as well now.

Comment: +1..............

Comment: Just FYI, you can use `% chktex 39` on a line to suppress warning 39 on that line.